# How to manipulate footer

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to write a footer in every page, but the text in footer (only a few words), is too close to the text of the page. So I want the footer text to shift little bit to the end of the actual page so that the actual text and footer text is easily distinguishable.

Comment: Do you mean that you want more space between your text and the footer?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. It always helps if you supply a small example document.
There are many packages for manipulating the footer and  page dimensions such as `fancyhdr` or `geometry` If you are using those packages then there may be specific commands, but basically you need to add additional length to `\footskip` so the footer is further away, and reduce `\textheight` so less text is put on the page to compensate. It is best to work in multiples of `\baselineskip` to ensure that a full page of text fits on the page without underfull box warnings.

The image shows the original `article` class 30pt skip and then the affect of adding `10\baselineskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\b{\a\a Red yellow blue green black white. \a}
\def\c{\a\a\par\b\b\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\par}
\def\d{\c\c\b\a\a\c\b\b\c\c}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@myfoot{\ps@plain
\def\@oddfoot{The footer text om page \thepage\dotfill}%
}
\makeatother

\addtolength\footskip{10\baselineskip}
\addtolength\textheight{-10\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myfoot}

\d
\end{document}
```